# Is there a way to apply modifier for mesh with shape key

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have created 50+ set of shape key for a game character customization. However, I was not aware once a mesh contain shape key all modifier(for my case is subdivision) are not allow to apply. I really don't wish to redo everything again.  Expect guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: check this https://github.com/przemir/ApplyModifierForObjectWithShapeKeys

Comment: thank you so much.